# What controls the first part of a Tomcat app's URL?

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm upgrading an old web app (was Tomcat 5 and JSF 1). I'm pretty new to Tomcat.

URLs into the app are all like this: `"http://localhost:8181/app/esp/..."`
But, currently the only way I can get the request through to the app is to use a URL like this: `"http://localhost:8181/esp/esp/..."`.

So, how and where do I need to configure this "/app"? (Bear in mind this was working fine in the previous version).

My current environment is Eclipse Kepler, Tomcat 7 and JSF 2. Tomcat starts fine from Eclipse and will display an html page with "Run as server", for example: `"http://localhost:8181/esp/esp/logout.html"`

But this page has a link to `"http://localhost:8181/app/esp/main"` which results in a message "HTTP Status 404 - /app/esp/main - The requested resource is not available." If I overwrite the "app" with "esp" the request is handled.

My web.xml (stripped down by now) is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    ESP

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>ESPServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ESPServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ch.eds.esp.controller.ESPServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ESPServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/esp/main/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Server.xml defines a Context in a Host, like this:

```
<Host appBase="webapps" debug="0" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
    <Context reloadable="true" path="/app" />
</Host>
```

So, to cut a long story short, a URL like this ".../**esp**/esp/mypage..." works, and a URL like this ".../**app**/esp/mypage..." doesn't. And the second form is the way it needs to work.

But why?  And how?

Following David99World's suggestion below, I tried changing these things. 
In Eclipse I changed the "Web Project Settings/Context Root" from "esp" to "app". This produced no change when trying to "run on server" from Eclipse.

I tried exporting a WAR file from my project (using "Export...) to either a esp.war or a app.war. Putting them into /webapps and clearing away the previous stuff and restarting Tomcat.

If I use esp.war, then the usual 404 happens.

If I use app.war, I have a folder structure /webapps/app/esp etc. And requesting `"http://localhost:8181/app/esp/main"` seems to give an interesting result. It first redirects to `"http://localhost:8181/app/esp/login.jsp"` which then results in an exception "bean exceptionHeaderBean not found within scope".

So, some good progress (I'll go find that bean). 
But how to get the same result from inside Eclipse?
I don't want to keep exporting a war to do each little incremental test.

Ah! You need to modify the Context Root (as noted above) - and *then* you need to (on the servers tab of Eclipse) "publish to server". Just stopping and starting are not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Change the war file name that builds from `app` to `esp`, the first location after `localhost:8080` is the deployed war application.

Comment: So, thanks for the suggestion. See extension to the original question for what happened, and a supplementary question.

Comment: I would vote your answer up - but I don't have enough reputation. Thanks again for the reply.